# How To Disable Blue Glow For Html Button In Ie9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I know this question has been asked before, but I'm having some difficulty getting it to work in IE9.  I have an html page with 3 forms in it (since each form contains a request to a different resource on a website).  The html looks like this:

```
<form action="/SomeController1/Action" method="get"><button name="action" value="someValue">Request the first thing</button></form>
<form action="/SomeController2/Action" method="get"><button name="action" value="someValue">Request the second thing</button></form>
<form action="/SomeController3/Action" method="get"><button name="action" value="someValue">Request the third thing</button></form>
```

I'm trying to disable the blue glow that is showing up on all three buttons when the page loads.  I think it looks really confusing...

The solution that I'm trying to implement, which doesn't seem to be working, is:

```
button
{
    outline-width: 0px;
    outline: none;
}
```

At any rate, the glow doesn't appear in Firefox or Chrome, it just seems to be appearing in IE.  I suppose I could just use one form and put 3 buttons in it, but this seems a bit more like a workaround rather than a solution.  Is there any way to do this using CSS or javascript?  Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks!

**Edit** -  Here's an image of the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was just hoping to get rid of the blue color.

You can't just get rid of it, because Internet Explorer uses the native buttons, from your system theme. Take a look at any system dialog box with a button, for example when you change your wallpaper.

You can only remove the blue inner glow if you're willing to style a decent looking button yourself, starting with setting a `border`/`background` (which disables using the native style).

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand what's going on a little better now:)

Answer (score 1):

with 'glow' you mean a border? in that case, just do;

```
button { border: 0; }
```

Comment: That's interesting.  If I turn the border off, it stops looking like a button.  I was just hoping to get rid of the blue color.  I can press the tab key a bunch of times key after the page loads, and when I tab through the buttons, the blue color disappears, but they still look like buttons and still have a border...  Although setting the border to zero solves the problem, it also seems to create another one...

Answer (score 1):

I don't have IE 9 to test---but generically in CSS, you should try

```
button:focus {
    outline:none;
    box-shadow:none;
}
```

Adapted from ["Removing the blue glow from an HTML text input when selected"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287803/removing-the-blue-glow-from-an-html-text-input-when-selected).