# Removing the blue glow from an HTML text input when selected

Tags: css, input

How can I remove the blue glow that surrounds a selected text input box using pure CSS?

Comment: Actually, in Google Chrome, it's orange. Just saying ;)

Comment: @wecsam: I was actually confused at first because I'm so used to Chrome's orange outline. :P

Answer (score 154, accepted):

This should do it:

```
input:focus {
    outline:none;
}
```

**EDIT (2015):** If you are designing for a wide audience, recall that the outline is often a critical accessibility feature for users who navigate via keyboards or require more apparent visual feedback. If you remove the outline, make sure to define an alternative focus state that provides appropriate visual feedback to your users.

Comment: Sometimes **box-shadow:none** is required too

Comment: neither works for me on Chrome `version 45.0.2454.101 m` :(

Comment: Due to restriction by browsers as select > options property outline is handled by shadowDOM. You can try [This] (http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) jQuery plugin

Answer (score 16):

I prefer a nice solid reset like:

```
input, textarea, select, a { outline: none; }
```

Outline 'none' on anchor tags prevents horrible focus outlines on many Android browsers.

Comment: outline for inputs is only allowed on focus

Comment: I prefer this one as well. Also, `select:focus` didn't seem to work for me. I don't see a problem with doing this at all. The `:focus` is unnecessarily explicit.

Comment: I needed to add  `!important` for it to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using bootstrap then you have to add  `box-shadow: none`

```
input:focus {
    outline:none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```